# Bash Array - Cant get input from a loop in to my array correctly

Tags: arrays, string, bash, integer, format

I run this script as

```
script.sh 'abcdefghijk123456789!@#$%^&' 'aaaa4444ged###'
```

it should be able to produce an array containing something like

```
1 1 1 1 15 15 15 15 7 5 23 23 23
```

with 12 indexes 0 - 11, but what i get is

```
1 1 1 1 1 5 1 5 1 5 1 5 7 5 2 3 2 3 2 3
```

with 20 indexes. 
   I want to populate a array with base numbers for a given char.
So i have a list of chars that we will be using in `$startstring` ie.
`abcc5678%` we can say that every char in `$startstring` is = to one char in the
`$charset` ie. `abcd5678!%`. This code finds what each `$startstring` char is equal
to `$charset`'s index number. That information is what i am trying to capture in a
array. Mostly it works except a bug where instead of the whole number 10 getting
stored in decoded[1] what happens is the number 10 is split in to 1 and 0 and
then both are put in under separate indexes. So instead of a "1 10 1" and 3
indexes i end up with 4 indexes with "1 1 0 1". Im sure im just handling my
variables the wrong way but i searched and searched and now my brain is gonna
explode so i came here for some relief. or hope of it anyway. Can someone tell
me the proper way to insert digits in to this `decoded[]` array?

```
#!/bin/bash
#declare -i decoded
charset=$1              
startstring=$2              


start=$((${#charset}-1))
echo "Setting up CharMap to CharSet"

for i in $(eval echo {0..$start})   
do                  
    echo $i " = " ${charset:$i:1}     
done            

echo "Proving Chars Were Mapped Correctly."

start2=$((${#startstring}))     
start3=$((${#charset}-1))         

for i in $(eval echo {0..$start2})  
do                          

    for p in $(eval echo {0..$start3})          
    do                          

        if [ "${startstring:$i:1}" == "${charset:$p:1}" ]   
            then                            
            echo "found that" ${startstring:$i:1}"=" $p 'from the charmap.'     
            decoded+=$p      #<--### I DONT THINK THIS IS WHAT I NEED ###       
            fi                          
    done                             
done                            
##################Just trying to print my new array#########################
start4=$((${#decoded}-1))               
echo 'Testing the array $decoded'
echo 'the var start4(length of $decoded) = '$start4 
echo 'this number should equal ----------> '$start2            
echo 'Printing out the $decoded array in a for loop'

for c in $(eval echo {0..$start4})          
do                          
   echo  ${decoded[$c]} ###DOESNT WORK LIKE I THOUGHT# also tried echo ${decode:$c:1}                     
done
```

Comment: You should indent your code properly

Comment: I, for one, have no idea what this script is trying to do. and given that it references undeclared variables of unknown type/content - I can't even check.

Comment: I added complete code and show how I run it, What the expected results are and what the results I would get are.

Comment: Use `for ((i=0; i<=start; i++))` in place of `for i in $(eval echo {0..$start})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decoded+=$p` appends $p as a string, not as an array entry. Essentially, you're creating the string "11111515151575232323" by appending all the index numbers together. (Actually, I get "00001414141464322222227" from your example, because of index bound problems. I'll let you worry about that...)

To store the decoded values as an array, set `decoded` to an empty array before the loop, and then use `decoded+=("$p")` to add `$p` as an element:

```
decoded=()  # create an empty array
for i in $(eval echo {0..$start2})  
do                          
  for p in $(eval echo {0..$start3})            
  do    
    if [ "${startstring:$i:1}" == "${charset:$p:1}" ]   
    then                            
      echo ${startstring:$i:1} "=" $p           
      decoded+=("$p")  # append $p as a new array element
    fi                          
  done                           
done
```

Then, to get the size of the array (rather than a string length), use `${#decoded[@]}`:

```
start4=$((${#decoded[@]}-1))
```

Comment: Awesome! And thank you for such a wonderful explanation. Gordon you made my brain better!!